# Append email value from marketo form to my success page as a URL parameter

Tags: url-parameters, marketo

Once the user clicks "submit" and the browser is re-directed to the thank you page, I need the page to pass the email variable as an appended parameter to the url, like this:

http://mywebsite.com/thank-you/?email=test@test.com

I have this code but it is passing all the parameters and it is not redirecting to the thank you page set up in marketo.

```
<script>
MktoForms2.loadForm("//app-xx00.marketo.com", "000-xxx-000", 0000, function(form) {
    // Add an onSubmit handler
    form.onSubmit(function(){
        // Get the form field values
        var vals = form.vals();
        dataLayer.push({
            'event': 'marketoFormSubmit',
            'marketoEmail': vals['Email'],
       });
    });
});
</script>
```

Maybe there is a simpler way?

Comment: I found a way to do this:

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to do this:

```
<script>
MktoForms2.whenReady(function (form) {
    form.onSuccess(function(values, followUpUrl) {
        var appendEmail = document.getElementsByName('Email')[0].value
        location.href = "http://google.com?email=" + appendEmail;
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Just update http://google.com to your thank you page URL.